# xp_cmdshell quotations and arguments size issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to pass large html from ms sql to exe file by:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'c:\path\index.exe' --body="<div style="font-family: Lato;""
```

This html can be very large more than 8k characters which I understand is the limit (win server 2008).
That is first problem and second is that when I try to pass html as argument from sql it **always strip quotations**.
Any suggestion how can I without problem pass any html to exe via sql command?

Comment: Don't use `xp_cmdshell`? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: We are moving from sp_senddbmail as we need to use oauth2 so we created exe file to send mails but from db we need to pass html content to send. But I was not aware of limitations.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off asking about how to implement `oauth2` with SQL Server and `sp_send_dbmail`. Certainly using `xp_cmdshell` is the wrong path here. Alternatively, perhaps you should be using an application to read the data from the database.

Comment: Yes reading from db is last option as that would lead to some bigger changes so trying to avoid for now. Is it possible to use oauth2 with sp_senddbmail?

Comment: I personally don't know, but that doesn't mean it can't be. The question may be better suited to [dba.se], depending how you word it though.

Comment: And perhaps the real problem is that you are trying to use sql server as some sort of email service in a fashion for which it is not well suited. Regardless, there are (and will likely always be) limits to the size of the command line buffer. Create a file and pass the file name? Pass the key to a particular row? Move the logic OUT of the database engine?